# Files losing all data when saving

Tags: php, file, upload, centos

Got a very complicated problem with little information on it. Ok I have a site that people upload files onto, those files are then base 64 encoded and sent to another site. The second site saves the file and then adds a database record for that file. Somewhere in this process, about 1 in 8 files are losing all content.

This system has been up for about 5 months, this error has only appeared in the last month, co-inciding with a server move. There is nothing in common with the files e.g. extension or source, nothing significant with time, and no php errors are being logged. I have got copies of the files that failed, and when I try to upload them, they work fine.

The first site wont let through a blank file, so it has to be happening in the second site, I believe maybe I have missed a php config option thats causing this. Just for thoroughness sake here is the code saving the file:

```
$fileName = time() . ($id->count + 1) . '-' . $this->post['jobId'] . $this->post['fileType'];
file_put_contents(DIR_TMP . "cvs" . DS . $fileName, base64_decode($this->post['cv']), FILE_APPEND);
```

The server in question is a Linux CentOS 6 64 bit.

So to be sum up, this problem started after a server move, only effects about 1/8 files and the files in question don't consistently fail. There is no pattern in file extension or timings (I'm not seeing multiple files being handled at the same time so I don't think the server is being overloaded) and no php error is being logged.

Any help would be much appreciated, though got very little to work on!

Comment: did you investigate possible file permissions problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found the answer, eventually managed to track the route the files were taking, and they were going from a previous version of the site. The moral of the story is when dealing with a whitelabelled site, keep in mind what version of the site is where!